# How can I display the amount when I click the drop down list in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image: Click here to see the image]

I just want to show the amount whenever I click the items in the drop down list.

I tried....

```
if(ddl.SelectedIndex == 1)
{
    txtAmount.Text = "240";
}
```

I used this:

```
string SQL = @"SELECT Product FROM Supplies"; 

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, con)) 
{
    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
    { 
        ddlProduct.DataSource = dr; 
        ddlProduct.DataTextField = "Product"; 
        ddlProduct.DataBind(); 
        ddlProduct.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select one...", "")); 
    }
```

Comment: how you bind the dropdown?

Comment: I used this

            string SQL = @"SELECT Product FROM Supplies";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, con))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    ddlProduct.DataSource = dr;
                    ddlProduct.DataTextField = "Product";
                    ddlProduct.DataBind();

                    ddlProduct.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select one...", ""));
                }

Comment: there is an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40927246/edit) button below your post. Please use this to add information to your current post

Comment: are you also getting price from the supplies table?

Comment: @AnkitkumarBhatt Yes I'm also getting the price from the supplies table.

Comment: so are you doing like ddlProduct.DataValueField = "Price"; ?

Comment: I want to show the price when I click the items in ddlProduct :)

Comment: I know but if you bind the price in the value field of dropdownlist then it will be very easy for you and dynamic as well.
never use index based condition to show price as if order of product got changed then you have to change the code.

Comment: it this correct?

                    ddlProduct.DataSource = dr;
                    ddlProduct.DataTextField = "Product";
                    ddlProduct.DataBind();
                    ddlProduct.DataValueField = "Amount";
                    ddlProduct.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select one...", ""));

Comment: write this `ddlProduct.DataValueField = "Amount"; `  before  `ddlProduct.DataBind(); `

Comment: I posted answer if you are binding Amount as value. It will be only one line code in your even. :)

Comment: Is the string connection correct?

string SQL = @"SELECT Product, Amount FROM Supplies";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select value field from the database and bind it to drop down list as below

```
string SQL = @"SELECT Product, Price FROM Supplies"; 
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, con))
{ 
 using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
 { 
  ddlProduct.DataSource = dr;
  ddlProduct.DataTextField = "Product";
  ddlProduct.DataValueField = "Price ";
  ddlProduct.DataBind(); 
  ddlProduct.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select one...", "")); 
 }
```

then, you can get the selected value and set the textbox text as below

```
protected void itemSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  txtAmount.Text = ddlProduct.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```

for that you need to add event on selectedindexchanged

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProduct" runat="server" 
       onselectedindexchanged="itemSelected" AutoPostBack="True" >
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: can I ask something again? Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Just write the below code in `selectedIndexChanged` event of your `dropdownlist`

```
txtAmount.Text = ddlProduct.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You add the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event to the DropDownList and set `AutoPostback` to `true`

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select one..." Value=""></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Silk" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Wool" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Cotton" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And in code behind

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal amount = 0;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownList1.SelectedValue))
    {
        //get amount from somewhere
        //amount = 
    }

    txtAmount.Text = string.Format("{0:C}", amount);
}
```